# iOS presentViewController in didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo causes app to lag

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

In my app I perform the following sequence:

1) I take an image with the device camera

2) In the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` I get back the image, I dismiss the `UIImagePickerController` and present a `viewController`, like this

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(void){
    [self presentNewViewController];
}];
```

presentNewViewcontroller looks like this

```
- (void) presentNewViewController {
    newViewController* newVC = [[newViewController alloc]init];
    [newVC setImage: selectedImage]; //selected Image comes from didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo


    [self presentViewController:newVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

This means right after the `UIImagePickerController` gets dismissed I instantly present a new controller.

This action runs on the simulator nicely, but on device it causes the app to lag. First I have to wait 2-3 seconds before the new `viewController` begins to come up and even then its animation runs slow and in pieces, not fluently.

At first I thought the picked image's too large, but then I compressed it using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` but the result haven't changed.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Put a break point on the `[self presentNewViewController];` line and check the debugger. Does this code runs on main thread or not?

Comment: yes, it runs on the main thread

Comment: Have you tried presenting the new view controller outside the completion block? Set a 0.2sec delay on it or something.

Comment: If it runs on main thread the only other thing in mind is to use Instruments to profile where the CPU is going. Emulator is ok as a starting point. Even if it doesn't delay you can still find out which methods are the CPU eathers